# ffmpeg + play video loop

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

Does anyone know how to make a video using ffmpeg + Opengl play continuously?. Because this is only played once

```
tiempo = glfwGetTime();
duracion = 1.0/25.0; // 1 second / 25 fps

while(1){

...        

  if(glfwGetTime() > tiempo + duracion){
    if(av_read_frame(pFormatCtx,&packet) >= 0){
      if(packet.stream_index == 0){
        avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx,pFrame,&frameFin,&packet);
        if(frameFin)sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,pFrame->data,pFrame->linesize,0,pCodecCtx->height,pFrameRGB->data,pFrameRGB->linesize);
      }
      av_free_packet(&packet);
    }
    tiempo += duracion;
  }

...

}
```

I know av_read_frame function (...) returns 0 if the end of file. But how do I make the function again returns a value other than zero? o How I can I make the video is constantly repeated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentqtion lavf_decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61">http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group_*lavf*_decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61

> 0 if OK, < 0 on error or end of file

so if <0 then call `av_seek_frame`

to return to start (same doc)

Comment: Would you need to reset the file reader or do anything beyond `av_seek_frame`, under regular circumstances? Would simply calling `av_seek_frame` be sufficient to loop in most cases?